# HibernateEnvers custom column name

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm implementing Hibernate Envers in the project I'm working on, and for this client the Tables and Columns in the database must follow a certain name pattern. The name pattern uses the table name to generate part of the column name and the table that saves the revision have a different name (of course) from the original table, therefore I need to be able to change the columns name of the table generated by Envers.

**How can I change the columns name of the entity's audition table?**

- I'm using hibernate 4.3.11-FINAL
- I had no trouble chaning the revision table (REVINFO) name and columns neither the entity's audition table name

Comment: Alexandru is correct, there is no way to customize the column names presently as the naming used is baked into the metadata read from the logical source table.  I have added a new JIRA issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10941. Feel free to add votes if this is something of real use.

Comment: Thanks @Naros, just voted =)

Comment: Well, since hibernate supports @Column annotation on properties I was hoping there was something like "@AuditColumn" or a parameter "columName" in the "@Audit" annotation

Comment: There is an attribute for `modifiedColumnName` but this is only used when the modified properties feature is enabled either globally or on a per audit property.  I can see if time permits to introduce this during the 6.x release cycle, but as always a pull request is welcomed :).

Comment: As one of the maintainers of the Envers code base, there presently is no way to change the name of the column nor does a workaround exist.  This is why I added HHH-10941.  You're welcomed to submit a pull request against that issue that adds this functionality if its critical.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Envers provides this functionality (of changing the names of the columns), i hope i am wrong.

Two options i could think of would be:

- go deeper in Envers code and try to see how you can customize the way data is written in audit, i am thinking of the column identification part
- change the way audit works, go for example for an approach that could use triggers

Answer (score -1):

REVINFO is the default table for default RevisionListener

You need to create custom revision Listener that implements RevisionListener
and your custom revsionEntity.

Custom Entity Listener:

```
public class CustomRevisionEntityListener implements RevisionListener {

@Override
public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
    CustomRevisionEntity revision = (CustomRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
    revision.setIPAddress("UserIPAddress");
}
}
```

And the custom entity, you can use any table name and any fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="anyTableName")
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionEntityListener.class)
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CustomRevisionEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    @Column(name = "rev")
    private int id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    @Column( name = "revtstmp")
    private long timestamp;


    @Column(name = "ipAddress")
    private String IPAddress ; 

}
```

Comment: Hi @Vivek, your answer only tackle the problem of changing the REVINFO table, but that is not what I was looking for... The REVINFO table is not the "audition table", it just saves the revisions information